# How to neatly sum values of histogram bins, given a value matrix and an associated category association matrix (bin association)

Tags: matlab, histogram

Consider the example following below, where I have a `10x10` matrix, say `A`, of random values in some range, say `[-5, 5]`. I quantize the values of `A` into 8 categories, `1, ..., 8`, such that an additional `10x10` matrix, say `qA`, describes the category association for each number in `A`. Finally, I produce the sums of all values assigned to each category. My question regards this final step.

```
myRange = 5; % values in open interval [-myRange, myRange]
A = myRange*(2*rand(10) - 1);
qA = uencode(A, 3, myRange)+1;

% (+) create "histogram" of sum of values assigned to each bin
myHistogram = zeros(8,1);
for i = 1:numel(A)
    myHistogram(qA(i)) = myHistogram(qA(i)) + A(i);
end

bar(myHistogram)
```

**Question:** Is the some neater way of doing this, specifically the counting step `(+)` above? (Some better alternative than explicitly iterating over each element in the matrix `A`?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as I was about to finish up and post my question I found a satisfying answer to it, however not here on SO. As [self-answering is encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), I'll post the Q+A instead of aborting this Q posting.

---

Hence, based on the following [Matlab Central thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/131536-sum-values-of-histogram-bins), *one* neater solution is as follows:

```
myRange = 5; % values in open interval [-myRange, myRange]
A = myRange*(2*rand(10) - 1);
qA = uencode(A, 3, myRange)+1;
% or, if you dont have Signal Processing Toolbox required for 'uencode'
% [~, ~, qA] = histcounts(A, -myRange:myRange/4:myRange);

% (+) create "histogram" of sum of values assigned to each bin
myHistogram = accumarray(qA(:), A(:), [8 1])
```

Possibly there's alternative/even better ways to do this, performing quantizing and bin value summation in same step?

Comment: `uencode` seems to be the dedicated function to do your task, and if you do have the required toolbox, its an nice option. Regarding the second part: `accumarray` is THE way to do it.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Thanks for feedback. I added an alternative solution to `uencode` in case one doesn't have access to the Signal Processing Toolbox.